# Count Values with same Month Timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, count, timestamp

I am struggling to count all the values that have the same Timestamp. This is how my database looks like:

[image]

Let's say I would like to get the amount of orders in May 2013. What is the right Syntax to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a count for a timestamp range, we can compare the timestamp column to a lower and upper bounds, for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.orderdate >= '2013-05-01 00:00:00' 
   AND t.orderdate <  '2013-06-01 00:00:00'
```

(All orders on or after the first second of May 1st AND before the first second of June.)

We can also do a similar comparison in an expression in the SELECT list, a conditional aggregation pattern:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(t.orderdate >= '2013-05-01' AND t.orderdate < '2013-06-01',1,0)) AS cnt_may
  FROM mytable t
```

equivalently

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(t.orderdate,'%Y-%m') = '2013-05' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt_may
  FROM mytable t
```

---

Note that the first query (with conditions in the WHERE clause on the bare `orderdate` column) can take advantage of an index that has `orderdate` as the leading column, to perform an efficient range scan operation.